# Invoke Flask CLI app from Python command line

Tags: python, flask, flask-cli

I'm pretty new to Python and Flask. I'm trying to execute a Flask app from the command line like :

```
python manage.py run
```

with 'run' being an argument I can change for different functions.

My code is this :

manage.py

```
import logging

from flask.cli import FlaskGroup

from server.app.main import create_app

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

app = create_app('dev')

cli = FlaskGroup(app)


@cli.command('run')
def run():
    _logger.info(f'run')
    return app.run(app.config.get('HOST'), app.config.get('PORT'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _logger.info(f'main')
    cli()
```

__init.py__

```
from flask import Flask
import logging

# import some config - ommitted for brevity

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def create_app(config):
    _logger.info(f'requesting config name: {config}')
    app = Flask(__name__)

    return app
```

When i run from the command line with Python it fails

```
python manage.py run
INFO:server.app.main:requesting config name: dev
INFO:__main__:main
Usage: manage.py run [OPTIONS]
Try 'manage.py run --help' for help.

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. Use the 'flask --app' option, 'FLASK_APP' environment variable, or a 'wsgi.py' or 'app.py' file in the current directory.
(venv) edge@edge-dev-machine:~/dev/flaskstuff/server/app$
```

it works with Flask from the command line

```
flask --app  manage.py run
INFO:server.app.main:requesting config name: dev
 * Serving Flask app 'manage.py'
 * Debug mode: off
INFO:werkzeug:WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
INFO:werkzeug:Press CTRL+C to quit
```

I figure I have something wrongs with the Flask CLI. Not sure what though.

So any help getting it to work with Python like :> python manage.py run bearing in mind i'll have a number of other argument as well as 'run'

Thanks